# Overridden QGraphicsView keyPressEvent steals events from focused QGraphicsWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I've built a custom `QGraphicsView` with defined behavior for certain key press events. The view displays a `QGraphicsScene` with `QGraphicsProxyWidgets`.

The problem is, as soon as I override the `keyPressEvent` in the view, the events don't get passed to the widgets, so I can't type in the text box. I want the widgets to steal keyPressEvents when they're focused.

I've tried setting the `ItemIsFocusable` flag on the proxy widgets and setting the focus policy to `StrongFocus` among other things. No luck so far.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Am I going about this wrong? Thanks for taking a look!

```
import sys
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore


class CustomView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super(CustomView, self).__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete, QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace):
            print('Deleting')



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Contact Details")
numberLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Telephone number")
numberEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
layout.addRow(numberLabel, numberEdit)
groupBox.setLayout(layout)

scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
proxy = scene.addWidget(groupBox)
proxy.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
proxy.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

view = CustomView(scene)
view.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override a method and do not call the implementation of the parent class then you will eliminate the default behavior, in your case sending the keyboard events to the items.

The solution is to invoke the keyPressEvent method of the parent class through super:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    super(CustomView, self).keyPressEvent(event)
    if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete, QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace):
        print('Deleting')
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @eyllanesc!
In order to prevent it when a widget is focused I added the following if statement:
`if self.scene().focusItem() is None:`